# Wrapping MudBlazor component inside custom component - Issue with @bind-Value

Tags: blazor, bind, blazor-server-side, mudblazor

I'm new to blazor and I came across MudBlazor components.  These are great, so I decided to implement them in my project. What I'd like to do is wrap each MudBlazor component that I use in my own custom component so that if I ever change anything in the future it will be simple (as is already the case as I already decided to change from Radzen to MudBlazor).  For the most part, this is fairly straight forward, with the one exception of the @bind-Value property. I can't seem to figure out how to get this to work.  Here is my custom component wrapping the MudBlazor "MudTextField".

```
<MudTextField @bind-Value="@BindTo" Label="@Label" Variant="@Variant" Margin="@Margin"></MudTextField>

@code {
    private string bindingValue;

    [Parameter]
    public string BindTo
    {
        get => bindingValue;
        set
        {
            if (bindingValue == value) return;
            bindingValue = value;
            BindToChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
        }
    }

    [Parameter] public EventCallback<string> BindToChanged { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public string Label { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public Variant Variant { get; set; } = Variant.Outlined;

    [Parameter] public Margin Margin { get; set; } = Margin.Dense;
}
```

This isn't working. When I set the BindTo parameter when calling my custom component, I can see the code in the set property being called, and the bindingValue is being set properly, but the property on the object I'm binding to isn't being updated. Do I need to do something else with the BindToChanged parameter? I saw that used in another example while researching the issue, but I don't really understand what it's supposed to do. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass through the triumverate of `Value`, `ValueChanged` and `ValueExpression` on to the MudBlazor component.

I don't work with MudBlazor so can't test this properly, and I only know how to build this as a RenderFragment rather than in Razor, but something like this should work:

```
    public class MyMudBlazorTextField<TValue> : ComponentBase
    {
        [Parameter]
        public TValue? Value { get; set; }

        [Parameter] public EventCallback<TValue> ValueChanged { get; set; }

        [Parameter] public Expression<Func<TValue>>? ValueExpression { get; set; }

        [Parameter] public string Label { get; set; }

        [Parameter] public Variant Variant { get; set; } = Variant.Outlined;

        [Parameter] public Margin Margin { get; set; } = Margin.Dense;

        protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.OpenComponent<MudTextField<TValue>>(0);
            builder.AddAttribute(1, "Variant", this.Variant);
            builder.AddAttribute(2, "Margin", this.Margin);
            builder.AddAttribute(3, "Label", this.Label);
            builder.AddAttribute(4, "Value", this.Value);
            builder.AddAttribute(5, "ValueChanged", EventCallback.Factory.Create(this, this.ValueChanged));
            builder.CloseComponent();
        }
    }
```

You then use the normal `@bind-value`

```
<MyMudBlazorTextField @bind-value=myfield ...../>
```

You're probably making a lot of effort for nothing.  Things like Variant and Margin as all specific to MudBlazor, and MudBlazor has some specific ways of building things, so unless you fix these in your components, you're muddying the waters on your generic components (to excuse a pun)!

#### Update

I've lifted some code from the `Account` page on the MudBlazor Dashboard project.  It sets the Text field with this function:

```
        public static void CreateMudTextField_0<T>(global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RenderTreeBuilder __builder, int seq, int __seq0, global::System.String __arg0, int __seq1, global::MudBlazor.Variant __arg1, int __seq2, T __arg2, int __seq3, global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback<T> __arg3)
        {
        __builder.OpenComponent<global::MudBlazor.MudTextField<T>>(seq);
        __builder.AddAttribute(__seq0, "Label", __arg0);
        __builder.AddAttribute(__seq1, "Variant", __arg1);
        __builder.AddAttribute(__seq2, "Value", __arg2);
        __builder.AddAttribute(__seq3, "ValueChanged", __arg3);
        __builder.CloseComponent();
        }
```

Base on this I've made a couple of adjustments to the code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  Unfortunately this didn't work for me.  It has the same affect as my previous attempt in my original post.

Comment: Also, you're correct that the variant and margin are MudBlazor specific, which could affect my ability to alter the components, but I doubt I'll actually change the variant and margin much from the defaults I set, so the components in the rest of my code won't reference them, and by wrapping the component, I can easily apply custom css in a css isolation file contained within that component.  I think it would be a lot cleaner that way.

Comment: I've just had a peek at the MudBlazor codebase and `MudBlazorTextField`.  I can see why it's not working.  They do things a little radically!!  I started down that design road and retreated back.  See my updated answer.  If that don't work I'm stuck.

Comment: That worked! Thanks!  My apologies, I'm not sure I implemented your original solution correctly the first time, so I'm not sure if it would have actually worked or not.  I didn't realize this was a separate component rendering entirely in c#. I was trying to include it as part of the razor component.

Comment: @Jason247.  NP.  The keep concept to understand is `Value`, `ValueChanged` and `ValueExpression`. `ValueExpression` is used to create `FieldIdentifiers` for OnFieldChanged and validation events, which MudBlazor doesn't use.

Answer (score 2):

I found another solution for getting it to work using a .razor component. I was pretty close originally. The code in the .razor component was correct. The issue was how I was passing the bind property when calling it. My apologies for not including that portion of code in my original request. I didn't think it was relevant.

I was trying to call it like this:

```
<MyInput BindTo=@"MyBindProperty" />
```

[but I needed to pass it to @bind-BindTo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75473682/109941)

```
<MyInput @bind-BindTo=@"MyBindProperty" />
```

The answer from MrC aka Shaun Curtis also works splendidly in a pure c# form.