# Difference between Value and @bind-Value?

Tags: checkbox, data-binding, binding, blazor, 2-way-object-databinding

I am looking at the docs for an `InputCheckBox` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.forms.inputcheckbox, and I see that it exposes `Value` to be bound to a desired boolean (`Gets or sets the value of the input. This should be used with two-way binding.`). Nonetheless, everywhere, people are using `@bind-Value` instead, Moreover, I cannot get `Value` to work.

How is this:

```html
<InputCheckbox @bind-Value="model.IsSelected"></InputCheckbox>
```

Different from this (And why this one does not work):

```html
<InputCheckbox Value="@model.IsSelected"></InputCheckbox>
```

I also noted that `@bind-Value` updates/notifies the model about the changes and updates any property that depends on `IsSelected`, while `Value` does not (probably unless explicitly specified?).
Additionally, when using `Value`, I need to also include a `ValueExpression` for the tag (or it won't render). What this `ValueExpression`?? In which scenarios would someone implement a different `ValueExpression`?

Has using `Value` any benefit? What will it take to make it work? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some more background information and an explanation of `InputBase`.

All `InputBase` inherited components implement three `Parameters`:

1. `Value` is the "in" value for the control - it's strongly typed.
2. `ValueChanged` is the "out" value for the control: A callback with a strongly typed value.
3. `ValueExpression` is a `Func` delegate that defines the actual model object/property.  It's used internally to create a `FieldIdentifier` object, which is used to identify the property in the `EditContext` and `ValidationStore`.

This page demonstrates two ways of setting up the bind.

The first does it manually and hooks up the change to a callback method.  You use this when you have other code you want to run in addition to just setting the value. (I'm setting a time stamp).

The second uses "syntatic sugar" provided by `Razor`.  `@bind-Value` tells the Razor compiler to build out a set of code to link the three Parameters with a common name of `Value` to te provided model property.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<InputCheckbox class="form-check"
               @bind-Value=this.model.Value />

<InputCheckbox class="form-check"
               Value=this.model.Value
               ValueChanged=this.OnValueChanged
               ValueExpression="() => this.model.Value" />

<div class="alert alert-info">
    Value: @this.model.Value
</div>

<div class="alert alert-info">
    @this.message
</div>

@code {
    private Model model = new();
    private string message = "No Message";

    private Task OnValueChanged(bool value)
    {
        this.model.Value = value;
        // You can do other stuff here if you need to
        this.message = $"Set at {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}";
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public class Model
    {
        public bool Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In the compiled low level C# code they are virtually the same thing.

Here's the full bind:

```cs
private RenderFragment FirstComponent => __builder =>
{
    __builder.OpenComponent<InputCheckbox>(5);
    __builder.AddAttribute(6, "class", "form-check");
    __builder.AddAttribute(7, "Value", RuntimeHelpers.TypeCheck<Boolean>(this.model.Value));
    __builder.AddAttribute(8, "ValueChanged", RuntimeHelpers.TypeCheck<EventCallback<Boolean>>(EventCallback.Factory.Create<Boolean>(this, RuntimeHelpers.CreateInferredEventCallback(this, __value => this.model.Value = __value, this.model.Value))));
    __builder.AddAttribute(9, "ValueExpression", RuntimeHelpers.TypeCheck<global::System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<System.Boolean>>>(() => this.model.Value));
    __builder.CloseComponent();
};
```

Here's the manual bind:

```cs
private RenderFragment SecondComponent => __builder =>
{
    __builder.OpenComponent<InputCheckbox>(11);
    __builder.AddAttribute(12, "class", "form-check");
    __builder.AddAttribute(13, "Value", RuntimeHelpers.TypeCheck<global::System.Boolean>(this.model.Value));
    __builder.AddAttribute(14, "ValueChanged", RuntimeHelpers.TypeCheck<EventCallback<Boolean>>(EventCallback.Factory.Create<Boolean>(this, this.OnValueChanged)));
    __builder.AddAttribute(15, "ValueExpression", RuntimeHelpers.TypeCheck<Expression<System.Func<System.Boolean>>>(() => this.model.Value));
    __builder.CloseComponent();
};
```

*Net7.0* @input-value:get and @input-value:set

Net7.0 implements more syntatic sugar to let you do binding in yet another way.  It also adds a third `@input-value:after` bind to provide a method to do the timestamp I showed above.

See this for the latest bind information - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. It helps a lot. It seems like there is a First/Second swap in the paragraph before the code (?)

Comment: Thank you for a hint about Net 7.0, here is the useful doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: @greenoldman - Thanks - added that reference to the answer.  It's a new article.

Answer (score 3):

As you noticed, `@bind-Value` delivers 2-way binding for Value.

I made the following demo once:

- Start a new Project from one of the templates
- Change the Counter Page a little:

```
<p role="status">Current count: @Count</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public int Count { get; set; } = 1;

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<int> CountChanged { get; set; }

    public Task IncrementCount()
    {
        return CountChanged.InvokeAsync(Count + 1);        
    }
}
```

- And then on the the Index page:

```
@page "/"
<div>
    <p>Counter1 : @count1</p>
    <p>Counter2 : @count2</p>
</div>

<Counter @bind-Count="count1"  />

<Counter Count="count2" CountChanged="UpdateCount2" />

@code {
    int count1 = 1;
    int count2 = 2;

    void UpdateCount2(int newValue)
    {
        count2 = newValue;
    }
}
```

When you now click the buttons on the Index page both Counter instances behave *exactly the same*.

This is because for `@bind-Count` the Razor compiler generates the `UpdateCount1` part (equivalent) behind the scenes. And that only works when there is a callback parameter with the right name: `CountChanged`.

See [Blazor data binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding)

Comment: This is far more than what I was expecting. I am not sure if I follow. 1) Why does `Value` alone does not work in the InputCheckBox then? 2) Do I need to explicitly implement the `xxChanged` to make it work? 3) Will Razor then create a `@bind-` for every public Parameter? How do you know about this? Is this documented?

Comment: To answer my last question and future reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: With `Value='x'` you get 1-way data binding. Not good enough for an input control. All the <InputXxx/> components implement a ValueChanged callback so that you don't have to do anything special.

Comment: And ad 3) : You write the `@bind-SomeProp="someVar"` part and then Blazor applies some pattern matching to find and use te callback.

Comment: When the docs mention: This should be used with 2-way binding, what does 
that means??

Comment: When you remove `CountChanged="UpdateCount2"` then count2 won't change anymore.