# Why does a [BindProperty] require an EventCallback?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have an inner component that has the following in it:

```
public partial class Address
{
    [BindProperty]
    [Parameter]
    public MapAddressDto? Value { get; set; }

    // lots of other stuff
}
```

And then in the outer razor file I have:

```
<Address 
    @ref="_addressElement"
    @bind-Value="@Model.Address"
    Selected="OnAddressSelected">
</Address>
```

I got to run and when it loads that page I get this exception:

```
InvalidOperationException: Object of type 'LouisHowe.web.Shared.Address' does not have a property matching the name 'ValueChanged'.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Reflection.ComponentProperties.ThrowForUnknownIncomingParameterName(Type targetType, string parameterName)
...
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperRunner.<RunAsync>g__Awaited|0_0(Task task, TagHelperExecutionContext executionContext, int i, int count)
LouisHowe.web.Pages.Pages__Host.<ExecuteAsync>b__23_1() in _Host.cshtml
+
    <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" param-InitialState="initialTokenState" />
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperExecutionContext.SetOutputContentAsync()
LouisHowe.web.Pages.Pages__Host.ExecuteAsync()
...
```

So I added `EventCallback<MapAddressDto> ValueChanged`

```
public partial class Address
{
    [BindProperty]
    [Parameter]
    public MapAddressDto? Value { get; set; }

    //[Parameter]
    public EventCallback<MapAddressDto> ValueChanged { get; set; }

    // lots of other stuff
}
```

And now it runs fine. I looked at some of the components in DevExpress' Blazor library and they appear to always have a ValueChanged event to go with every Value property. So I'm guessing that a `[BindProperty]` requires a matching `EventCallback`.

Does it? And why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it?

Yes.

> And why?

There is no free lunch, something has to update the bound variable.

Note that `Value` is most common but you can also have `@bind-Size`, and that requires a SizeChanged callback.

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75466555/60761) for more details.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. But I don't see why that requires the ValueChanged method. As you showed in your link bind-Count didn't use CountChanged. It is what it is, but I don't see why it's required. Any-who, thanks.

Comment: No, `@bind-Count="count1"` definitely requires `CountChanged`. You can see it in the generated .razor.g.cs file.

Comment: I understand that it does require it. My comment is that I don't understand why they made that a requirement.

Comment: I think I've figured it out. When you add a @bind-Whatever, it creates an underlying WhateverChanged() that it uses to update that value.

Comment: Not how I would describe it. `@bind-Whatever` creates a method that handles (subscribes to) WhateverChanged, but the component has to explicitly define Whatever and  WhateverChanged parameters.

Comment: I defer to your explanation as you understand Blazor about a million times better than me. Thank you again.