# Blazor Component - How can I implement custom compile-time parameter validation?

Tags: c#, validation, blazor, compile-time, blazor-component

@MrC aka Shaun Curtis detailed the `@bind-Value` syntactic sugar for components [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75473682/109941).

As some may know, you may specify `@bind-Value` or `@ValueChanged`, but **not** both. If you specify both, your code won't build and you'll get a [RZ10010 error](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:S_qkd7LsdxAJ:https://docs.devexpress.com/Blazor/403279/troubleshooting/common-component-issues/the-component-parameter-value-changed-is-used-two-or-more-times&hl=en&gl=us).

> RZ10010: The component parameter ‘ValueChanged’ is used two or more times for
> this component. Parameters must be unique (case-insensitive). The
> component parameter ‘ValueChanged’ is generated by the ‘@bind-Value’
> directive attribute.

---

So I cite `RZ10010` as an example of Blazor component compile-time parameter validation, implemented natively by .NET Core.

My question is:

> How can I implement my own Blazor component compile-time parameter validation?

For instance, if `MyComponent.razor` looked like this:

```
[Parameter]
public string ParameterA { get; set; }

[Parameter]
public string ParameterB { get; set; }
```

And I wanted to allow a value for `ParameterA` or `ParameterB`, but **not** both, how would I do that?

Comment: I believe (but don't know for certain) that `RZ10010` is provided by a Roslyn Analyzer added to the MSBuild process by the Razor/Blazor SDK's `.targets` files.

Comment: @Dai: Interesting. That wouldn't entirely surprise me if true.

Comment: I found it just now - look inside `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Razor.dll` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.dll`

Comment: Just to clarify, `RZ10010` _specifically_ isn't in either of those assemblies I mentioned (because it's Blazor-specific, not general Razor), but other Razor diagnostics (like `RZ10003` and `RZ9995`) _are_ located in there. I assume there's some Razor-for-Blazor assembly somewhere in your computer that does contain the `RZ10010` diagnostic. Use ILSpy's "Search for: Constant" feature to find it.

Comment: An EditForm requires either a Model or an EditContext. The only error reporting is at runtime. So I don't think there is an easy way to get a compile-time error.

Comment: @HH: Yes - That could very well be the case.

Comment: You can only categorically apply your rule at runtime when the component instance is instantiated by the Renderer and `SetParametersAsync` is run.  Therefore, I would build some logic into `SetParametersAsync` to test and throw an exception as required.  Just as @HH suggests happens with `EditContext`.