# Is it fine to change the Blazor component's parameter inside the target component class?

Tags: c#, vue.js, blazor

The Blazor has been inspired by Vue, and the Blazor "components' parameters" has the same concept as Vue "components' props". In Vue and similar frameworks, the changing of the props inside the class to which these props are belong is the gross violation.

What about Blazor? Just tried to do this - looks like works fine.

```cs
using Utils;
using YamatoDaiwaCS_Extensions;


namespace FrontEndFramework.Components.ModalDialog;


public partial class ModalDialog : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase
{

  [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Parameter]
  public string? title { get; set; }
  
  [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Parameter]
  public required bool mustDisplay { get; set; }

  [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Parameter]
  public bool noDismissingButton { get; set; } = false;
  
  [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Parameter]
  public required Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback onPressDismissingButtonEventCallback { get; set; }
  
  [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Parameter]
  public required Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
  

  protected async void onPressDismissingButton()
  {
    this.mustDisplay = false; // HERE
    await this.onPressDismissingButtonEventCallback.InvokeAsync();
  }
  
 }
```

Comment: Side note: use PascalCasing for parameters. That is a general C# rule but even more important in Blazor. camelCasing is for JSon and HTML.

Comment: @ℍℍ, why this rule is so important?

Answer (score 1):

It is officially frowned upon to overwite parameters from within a component after the first render.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/overwriting-parameters?view=aspnetcore-8.0

> Our general guidance is not to create components that directly write
> to their own parameters after the component is rendered for the first
> time.

This means that setting sensible defaults is fine, but any private updates may be overwritten when the parent state changes.

A strategy you can use is to bind to another private property that can derive its value from parameters and internal state.

I have mocked up a simple example below - this just demonstrates the concept, you will need to apply your own logic.

```html
@*Bind to a private property that is derived 
from public parameters and private state*@
@if (Display)
{
  <div>
    Hello, world!
  </div>
}

<button @onclick="@OnPressDismissingButton">
  Click me!
</button>
```

```cs
@code {
  // public parameter - should not be updated by this component
  // after the first render
  [Parameter]
  public bool MustDisplay { get; set; } = true; // <-- OK to set default

  [Parameter]
  public required EventCallback 
    OnPressDismissingButtonEventCallback { get; set; }
  
  // store private state in other properties
  private bool ButtonPressed { get; set; }
  
  // derive bindable state using a combination of public and private state
  private bool Display => MustDisplay && !ButtonPressed;
  
  protected override void OnParametersSet()
  {
    // alternatively manage internal state in this method
  }

  private async Task OnPressDismissingButton()
  {
    ButtonPressed = true;
    await OnPressDismissingButtonEventCallback.InvokeAsync();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Same rules apply.  Here's a MS docs article on the subject

[Overwriting Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/overwriting-parameters?view=aspnetcore-8.0)

`[Parameter]` is just an attribute that identifies which properties the Renderer needs to pass from the parent to the child component.  Within the component they are just properties.

The reason you shouldn't mutate their state within the component is they are set every time the Renderer calls `SetParametersAsync` on the component.

```cs
    public virtual Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
    {
        parameters.SetParameterProperties(this);
        if (!_initialized)
        {
            _initialized = true;

            return RunInitAndSetParametersAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            return CallOnParametersSetAsync();
        }
    }
```

The `ParameterView` object contains the current values/references of all the defined parameters. This line applies those values to the properties in the component.  Note it's a rather expensive operation as it uses reflection.

```cs
parameters.SetParameterProperties(this);
```

This MS article provides some additional information on components:

[Component Performance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/performance?view=aspnetcore-8.0)

And this section shows how you can break the rule to set them manually.

[Set parameters manually](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/performance?view=aspnetcore-8.0#implement-setparametersasync-manually)

If you do want to mutate values, create an internal global variable you set in `SetParametersAsync` and then mutate it as you wish, using your own logic to decide how to update the internal value,

The basic pattern for overriding `SetParametersAsync` is:

```cs
public override Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
{
   // Always do this FIRST
   parameters.SetParameterProperties(this);

   // do what you want

   // call the base to run the lifecycle stuff passing in an empty ParameterView so nothing gets reset.
   base.SetParametersAsync(ParameterView.Empty);
}
```

I see you are writing a Modal Dialog.  There are several free ones available often with access to the code repositories so you can see how they are implemented.  There's even a rather old implementation of mine here - [A Simple Blazor Modal Dialog Implementation](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5286721/A-Simple-Blazor-Modal-Dialog-Implementation) which shows how to implement async behaviour in opening and closing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is disadviced. Strongly.

Because when you change a parameter that is not (automatically) reflected in the parent component. It creates '2 versions of the truth'.

A parameter should always be changed by the parent:

```
protected async void onPressDismissingButton()
{
  // this.mustDisplay = false; // remove this
  await this.onPressDismissingButtonEventCallback.InvokeAsync();  // parent decides
  // and now the new value will be set in OnParametersSet
}
```

For a full 2-way binding see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75466555/60761).